# How to make a custom legend when a plot overlays another using ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to make a stacked histogram plotting two different variables. There is a variable called `T1`, and another variable called `T2`. These two variables have two different states, one that happened before, and another that happened after.
I want to have one plot where I'll show both `T1` and `T2` in one column, their state before and after, but using two different colours (one that indicates the state before, and another that indicates the state after).

This is the code snippet I have so far:

```
pre <- as.data.frame( matrix( nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE,c(60,"T1",40,"T2") ) )
post <- as.data.frame( matrix( nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE,c(70,"T1",50,"T2") ) )
pre$V1 <- as.numeric(as.character(pre$V1))
post$V1 <- as.numeric(as.character(post$V1))

ggplot() +
geom_histogram(stat="identity", fill=c(rep("red",2)), data=post, aes(x=V2, y=V1, fill=V2, colour="Before")) +
geom_histogram(stat="identity", fill=c(rep("green",2)), data=pre, aes(x=V2, y=V1, fill=V2, colour="After")) +
scale_x_discrete("x axis") +
scale_y_continuous("y axis", limits = c(0, 100)) +
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","green"))
```

So the plot looks amazing, however my question is now, how can I get a proper legend? So I need to have one colour for `"After"` and another for `"Before"`, but not as lines, rather as filled boxes.

Comment: So you want the red coloured area to only resemble the difference between the "before" and "after" values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, as you are making barplot then use `geom_bar()`. Then for the `fill=` and `color=` inside `aes()` use the same names and then adjust color and fill with `scale_..` functions.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  data=post, aes(x=V2, y=V1, fill="Before",color="Before")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", data=pre, aes(x=V2, y=V1, fill="After",color="After")) +
  scale_x_discrete("x axis") +
  scale_y_continuous("y axis", limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend",values = c("green","red"))+
  scale_color_manual("Legend", values = c("red","green"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I've been after! In my case plot was a bit different, with a black line across the box in the legend, however I put `scale_color_manual("Legend", values = c("black","black"))` and now it's perfect! Thanks!